# R conditional subset gives odd output with no warnings

Tags: r

I'm using the following code to return a subset of data with the following conditions:

1. sample_id's contain "BLUE"
2. result_value field > result_limit (these two columns contain only numbers)

---

```
table1 <- subset(table1, grepl("*BLUE", sample_id) & (result_value > result_limit))
```

At first I was getting a bad output (no warnings, but records that didn't follow the second condition), then I realized the result_value & result_limit columns were classified as "character", and not "numeric". It worked fine after reclassifying them as numeric. My question is, shouldn't R be returning a warning since I was performing a calculation on non-numeric fields before it returns a funky output? And does anyone know what odd things it might be doing when performing this test on character fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing character is posibble. For example

```
> 'A' < 'a'
[1] FALSE
> 'a' < 'b'
[1] TRUE
> 'a' > 'b'
[1] FALSE
> '1' > '2'
[1] FALSE
> '1b' > '1a'
[1] TRUE
### check that
> '12311231' > '543242'
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Interesting. This could come in handy! I'll have to be more careful about proper classification!